# Where is Android Studio saving the "excluded folders" list?

Tags: android, android-studio

On Android Studio Electric Eel. I wanted to share my list of excluded folders with my team. I assumed this would be saved on the .iml files, or possibly in workspace.xml. This is not the case. I looked for "excludeFolder" in all my .ideas folder, again no success. Where are these settings stored now?

Comment: Try `projectDir/yourProjectName.iml`

Comment: Thanks, but no such file exist. There's `projectDir/.ideas/modules/app.iml` and `projectDir/.ideas/modules/app.main.iml`, neither of these seems to have the settings I'm looking for